# Bootstrap 3 - Scrollable content div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, scroll, grid

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to make a scrollable content DIV.
I have a grid with a left side navigation and a top bar and in the
middle I have the content that should be scrollable.

It works when I use a fixed height on the content div...but I want
to use 100% instead.

```
<div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
some content...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body
{
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

How could I get this to work with height:100%;

Thanks!

Comment: Does overflow-y: scroll work for you? Sorry haven't tested as on my phone

Comment: I don't get any vertical scrollbar in the content DIV with the above code...so overflow-y doesn't seem to help.

Comment: hmmm. Having read your post again I just want to check do you need a scrollable div or do you just want to make your left nav and top nav fixed while the rest of the page moves similar to the boostrap docs pages?

Answer (score 30):

You can add **pre-scrollable** class for the div you want to scroll.

If you search the **.css** there is a **max-height** but you cant edit. So you have sure it will maximize the page in the window for that max value.

Hope it helps, i used the same for a one-page with scrollable divs.

Comment: This works for me e.g. <div class="well well-sm pre-scrollable">
    <samp id="containerLog" class=""></samp>
</div>